# non-reversible (irreversible) MCMC Langevin sampling methods. Intuition

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, stochastic-processes, convergence

Mathematically it is well understood that irreversible samplers are superior to reversible samplers in a number of ways. For example, if we want to sample from a distribution $\pi \propto e^{-U}$ by building a Markov Chain from the Langevin dynamics :

$$dX_t=-\nabla U(X_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dW_t,$$

(for which $\pi$ is reversible), then it turns out the perturbed dynamics

$$dY_t=-\nabla U(Y_t)dt+C(Y_t)dt+\sqrt{2}dW_t,~~~\text{div}(C(x)\pi(x))=0$$
(for which $\pi$ is only stationary) performs better, see this work https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-016-1565-1.

Is there any heuristic reasoning why non-reversible samplers will converge faster to equilibrium and perform better at sampling?